# Match criteria within one string to add HTML and replace original string

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, pipe

Here is a [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw7smj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). What I have done so far.

I am building an angular application. Unfortunately I have been given a huge single string value. Parts of this string need to be "**bolded**". I have identified that after every `:`(colon) up until every new line `\n` there needs to be an insertion of `<strong>` tags.

**String example**

```
"Football: great\nCricket: ok\nTennis: Poor"
```

Currently, it looks like this:

Football: great
Cricket: ok
Tennis: Poor

But need it to look like this:

Football: **great**
Cricket: **ok**
Tennis: **Poor**

I thought the best way would be to create a pipe to pass the string through, filter out the words after the colon and before the newline with regex.

Take that filtered out word or words and add strong tags to it then replace the matched words back into the original string.

I am almost there, however I can't get the loop right, it seems that it identifies `" "` and also applies each matched word to all the matches so I would only ever get one returned. So I get returned:

Football:
Cricket:
Tennis:

or

Football: **ok** **ok**
Cricket: **ok** **ok**
Tennis: **ok** **ok**

Here is a [stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gw7smj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). What I have done so far.

**boldPipe.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Sanitizer, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { noop } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
    name: 'boldSpan'
})
export class BoldSpanPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: Sanitizer) {}

    transform(value: string): any {

        const regex = /[^:]*$/gim;
        return this.sanitize(this.replace(value, regex));
    }

    replace(str, regex) {
        const matched = str.match(regex);
        debugger;
        matched
            ? matched.forEach(foundString => {
                    foundString = foundString.substring(1, foundString.length);

                    str = str.replace(regex, `<strong>${foundString}</strong>`);

              })
            : noop;
        return str;
    }

    sanitize(str) {

        return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: to make a newline take affect when rendered, add a double space before it.

Comment: Note that `[^:]*` will greedily match newlines up until the next `:`. You could change it to a lazy match `[^:]*?$` and yours would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match at least one char other than a colon with `/[^:]+$/gm`, or even `/[^:\r\n]+$/`, and then replace with the `<strong>$&</strong>` pattern where `$&` refers to the whole match value:

```
export class BoldSpanPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: Sanitizer) {}

    transform(value: string): any {
        const regex = /[^:]+$/gm;
        return this.sanitize(this.replace(value, regex));
    }

    replace(str, regex) {
        return str.replace(regex, '<strong>$&</strong>');
    }

    sanitize(str) {
        return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `str.replace(/:(.*)/g, ":<strong>$1</strong>"`
This way doesn't worry about newlines.